# Is it a redundant phrase?

Tags: meaning

I came across this:

> "The door between Russia and America is slam shut."

How to better understand "slam shut"? Is it like a door that was closed very noisily by applying too much force?

Comment: Most likely "slammed shut"?

Comment: Where did you come across it?

Comment: Take more care with your quotes. Country names require capital letters. And how would you understand the quote?

Answer (score 1):

To **slam something shut** is to close it with a lot of force, often resulting a loud noise or shock. To give a few examples:

> He put the bag in the back seat and **slammed the car door shut**. 
> After seeing that the food inside was moldy, he **slammed the tupperware shut**.

This verb phrase is a common use of the word *slam*, which almost always involves a large or excessive amount of force, noise, and shock. Wiktionary [defines it](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/slam#Etymology_1) (in part) as

1. To shut with sudden force so as to produce a shock and noise.
2. To put in or on a particular place with force and loud noise.

The example you give is ungrammatical in almost all interpretations. Since *slam shut* is a verb phrase, it needs to be something like:

> The door between Russia and America **has been slammed shut** 
> The door between Russia and America **was slammed shut**

Note that these do not mean the same thing.

This quote is based on the idiom **to shut (or; slam) the door on** someone, which means to refuse to talk or engage with. Some examples [taken from wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/shut_the_door_on):

> Contentment with the past may no longer **shut the door** on science. 
> Let's **shut the door** on conflict. 
> Yet Tressel didn't **slam the door** on the possibility that Wells might still play in Saturday's game against Ohio University.

The adjective (or adjectival phrase) *slam-shut* apparently does see a small amount of use (on the internet at least), but it is very very usual and I had never heard of it before googling it here.

Comment: Slamming a Tupperware container shut might require special skills.